# Programmatically click an Ext.dom.Element ( NOT a button ) on ExtJS 6.6

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, extjs

I got a NEARLY same problem with this guy on the ExtJS Forum but this guy asked this question 10 years ago and the man who answered the question also did not replied my message [here](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?130917-SOLVED-How-to-simulate-a-real-mouse-click-on-a-button-ExtJS-element).

He said that the button handler must be triggered but in my project, it is not a button, it is an Ext.dom.Element ( how could you find the post 10 years ago and not sure that it is still exist ? )

When finding the solution, I also tried this solution but I still [failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132331/programmatically-click-a-button-in-extjs)

==> Overall: how to programmatically click an Ext.dom.Element which is NOT a button in ExtJS6.6?

```
While: 
component.click(); //which will return component.click is not a function
component.fireEvent("click"); //only returning "true"
component.fireEvent("clickEvent"); //only returning "true"
component.fireEvent("onTriggerClick"); //only returning "true"
```

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using? What error do you get when you try `component.dom.click()`?

Comment: Would it help to allow you to click the component or do you need the JS/dom click? I am not really understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: Could you please update the snippet above so it also shows how `component` is created or where its value is coming from?

Also, could you share why do you think the click is not happening? Do you have an event handler? What should happen after the element is clicked?